# Disabling editing QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to make it so under certain conditions, it is impossible to edit a QLineEdit widget. Ideally, it would look something like:

```
QLE_On = QCheckBox("Non-editable?")
generic = QLineEdit()

if QLE_On.isChecked():
#disable editing of generic
```

Looking at the docs, .isReadOnly might be one possible option how to achieve what I'm looking for, but I'm not quite sure  how to implement that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to establish that the `QLineEdit` is editable or you should not use the `setReadOnly()` function.

You can know the state of the checkbox synchronously and asynchronously through the `checkState()` function and the `stateChanged` signal. In your case you need both, the first to set the initial value and the second when you do a check through the GUI, in your case the following code is the solution:

```
generic.setReadOnly(QLE_On.checkState()!=Qt.Unchecked)
QLE_On.stateChanged.connect(lambda state: generic.setReadOnly(state!=Qt.Unchecked))
```

Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w=QWidget()
w.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

QLE_On = QCheckBox("Non-editable?")
generic = QLineEdit()

generic.setReadOnly(QLE_On.checkState()!=Qt.Unchecked)
QLE_On.stateChanged.connect(lambda state: generic.setReadOnly(state!=Qt.Unchecked))

w.layout().addWidget(QLE_On)
w.layout().addWidget(generic)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing: is there any way to set the QLineEdit to a fixed value before it's locked down and unable to be edited? I tried making it connect to a function when its state was changed that would call setText on the QLineEdit, but it never seemed to work.

Answer (score 11):

Simply make the `lineEdit` uneditable by making it `False`:

```java
self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to be selectable then use:

```
self.lineEdit.readOnly
```